# What's a good pip/setuptools compliant version number for a fork of a package?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am forking a python package, where I expect the package author to merge my changes in the near future.  The package author doesn't release very often, so I expect to have my temporary fork as a dependency for some of my other packages.  I need to create an appropriate version number for my fork that is pip/setuptools compliant.

Let's say the current version is `1.6.4`, and I expect the author's next release to be `1.6.5`.  Would an appropriate version for the fork be `1.6.4.1` or `1.6.5.dev20140520`?  Both seem to be compliant with PEP440, but I also have had experience with recent versions of `pip` not finding `dev` releases unless you specifically use the `pre` flag.  It seems that `1.6.4.1` would be a good choice, but I don't know how happy `pip` will be with a `N.N.N.N` format (e.g. will `pip` treat it as a `pre` release?).

Is there some standard convention for this?  Note, I don't want to change the name of the author's package, but I do need a temporary fork that my other packages can install with minimal issues.

Comment: There's no standard. In fact I've yet to see a good versioning scheme (and partial order on the version numbers) for packages that may fork; 1.6.4-yourname-1.0 is used by Linux packagers.

Comment: That's the convention I have been using for years in such a situation.  However, the issue is that the python package installers don't recognize N.N.N-fork-N as a valid naming convention, so I'm looking for something else.

Comment: Doesn't pip handle version control URLs in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that `requirements.txt` could be used to ensure that whatever I name the thing, it is found.  That should work if you are trying to install the package as a dependency, which *is* the case I was most interested in.  It wouldn't work if you were trying to install the fork as a stand-alone, which I expect people would want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there's not an official convention for naming a fork for a python package.   As @larsman pointed out in the question comments, a standard convention forking `package-1.6.4` is `package-1.6.4-forkname-0.1` -- and while this has been used by the Linux community (and others) for years, it has recently lost favor for python packages.  One of the main issues is that this convention does not follow accepted versioning conventions used by `pip` -- and thus has garnered less use in recent years for python packages.  If you do a search for "fork" on pypi's package index (https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=fork&submit=search) you'll see that it seems there are two common `pip`-compliant cases emerging:

1. `package-forkname-1.6.4`
2. `forkname-1.6.4`, where `forkname` is a "clever" variant on `packagename` (e.g. `PIL` and `pillow`)